# How to get the local time at a specific moment at any location on the globe

Tags: c#, time, timezone-offset, datetimeoffset

I need to know how to get the local time at a specific moment at any location on the globle.

Something like this:

```
DateTime localTime = GetLocalTime(utcDateTime, city);
```

or

```
DateTime localTime = GetLocalTime(utcDateTime, longitude, latitude);
```

Is there some API in the NET Fx, or Windows API or global web service to get the local time at a specific moment at a location on the globle?

Comment: Get a timezone: [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates) and then get a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  Google API SDK to get the location. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro

```
public DateTime GetLocalTime(
DateTime utcDate, double latitude, double longitude )
{
var request = new TimeZoneRequest
{
ApiKey = _apiConfiguration.GoogleApiKey,
Location = new Location(latitude, longitude),
TimeStamp = utcDate,
Sensor = false
};

var response = GoogleMaps.TimeZone.Query(request);

if (response.Status != GoogleMapsApi.Entities.TimeZone.Response.Status.OK) 
return utcDate;

var offset = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(response.RawOffSet + response.OffSet);
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone(response.TimeZoneId, offset, response.TimeZoneName, response.TimeZoneName);
var localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcDate, timeZone);

return localTime;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That is exactly what I was looking for!